# esxi vmware iscsi-datastore lost after power outage

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, datastore

I usually just try to find my own solution until it just works, this time not so much..

I have a ESXi cluster, with 2 hosts and 1x datastore cluster. Earlier today after a power outage, everything went down including the iSCSI SAN.

When I got everything up and running again, the datastore is missing. 
I've done rescans, restarts and everything inbetween to get it to work but without any luck.

When I try to add a new datastore, I find the "missing" one, in the list so I mark it and click new. The problem is that I'm really scared I "recreate the partition" and lose all my data? Question really is: Can I? without losing my data!

Comment: What type of SAN is it?

Comment: It's iSCSI on Ubuntu

Comment: Strange part is also that I have 3 datastores, only one of them is gone.

They are on the same SAN but different drives, both affected by the power failure. 

2 separate lun's